# The degeneracy of the ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

I wonder how can i know the degeneracy of the ground state of certain elements?

I'm doing Boltzmann distribution problems, and I'm not sure what to do. I have to calculate ratio of ions in 3p excited state, regarding ground state for Na$^+$ and Mg$^{+2}$ ions. I think that 3p degeneration is 6, but I don't know what else to put in this fraction.

Also, I've noticed that sometimes we just ignore that part of equation (count it as one) but I'm not sure when I'm allowed to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Each s sublevel (l=0) can be occupied by 2  electrons.

Each p sublevel (l=1) can be occupied by 6 electrons.

Each d sublevel (l=2) can be occupied by 10 electrons.

Each f sublevel (l=3) can be occupied by 14 electrons.

Each sublevel can be occupied by 4l + 2 electrons.

But are you sure that it is Na+ and Mg2+ (not Na and Mg+)?  Na+ and Mg2+ don't have any valence electrons.